# Does Node's assert module provide a way to perform deep equality checks without coercion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, equality, assertions

I'd like the following to throw an AssertionError:

```
assert.deepEqual([1, 2, 3], ['1', '2', '3'])
```

According to the [assert module documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html), this appears not to be possible.

The following sentence from the [substack/node-deep-equal README](https://github.com/substack/node-deep-equal/blob/0.1.0/README.markdown#deepequala-b-opts), though, suggests otherwise:

> The default is to use coercive equality (`==`) because that's how `assert.deepEqual()` works by default.

Answer (score 0):

The docs from `substack/node-deep-equal` say exactly the same — node.js built-in implementation uses `==`, substack's uses `==` by default, `===` if `opts.strict` is `true`.

Comment: The author decision to write "that's how assert.deepEqual() works __by default__" rather than "that's how assert.deepEqual() works" suggests that Node's behaviour is customizable. Perhaps I'm reading too much into it, though.

Comment: Fair enough. In such cases you can just look at node.js source — this is the line https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/assert.js#L180

Comment: Thanks for tracking that down. Here's a permalink: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.21-release/lib/assert.js#L174